# How to keep thread running after it loose scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I am tring to make a DLL

My Exe Program calls the functions of DLL

In a certain function, i create a thread. 
The thread will take 30-40 minutes to finish

Meanwhile i have other things to do in Exe

[image]

We cannot do anything with the exe program. Actually it is a game server, which has the option to load plugins(dlls) and squirrel embedded so that we can call functions of dlls from script of game server.

Comment: Maybe you need to have a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/). And it seems that you need some good C++ [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The problem is either i have to wait for the thread to finish, which is not possible. Or i have to declare the thread somewhere outside and initialize inside the function. so that it will not loose scope. But not working

Comment: I don't get your point. Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: supplied the main question with a picture.

Comment: Just make function1 returning immediately after starting the thread, and the exe will be able to do whatever it wants. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I used winapi's CreateThread function and i got what was wanted.